# How to use LINQ remove a subset of list with certain criteria?

Tags: c#, linq

Following code will throw runtime exception `"Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."`

```
List<string> l = new List<string>();
l.Add("a");
l.Add("b");
l.Add("c");
foreach (string s in l.Where(s => s.CompareTo("a")>0))
    l.Remove(s);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't remove items from a collection while enumerating over it.

In this case, I'd use [`List<T>.RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx):

```
l.RemoveAll(s => s.CompareTo("a")>0);
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I needed. any suggestion on if the type was not IList<T> but  IEnumerable<T>?

Comment: @user1105127 `IEnumerable<T>` isn't editable, so you wouldn't **remove** elements.  Instead, you'd *filter* the collection by using `Enumerable.Where()`, and assigning it to a new variable (or re-assign to the `IEnumerable<T>`)

Answer (score 2):

You need to think what it means to filter by some condition, and then what it means to remove by some condition. (Hint: they're logical opposites.)  What your're doing is a far more convoluted way of stating:

```
var result = l.Where(s => ! (s.CompareTo("a")>0));
```

Comment: Thanks, in my case I'd need a in-place removal rather than get a new result.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do is do a `ToList` after your linq query. Something like

```
List<string> l = new List<string>();
l.Add("a");
l.Add("b");
l.Add("c");
l = l.Where(s => s.CompareTo("b") > 0).ToList();
```

`l` will only contain `c` in the end.

Also like `Jon` mentioned List also has [RemoveAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) method that you could use

`l.RemoveAll(s => s.CompareTo("b") <= 0);`

does the same thing as above but notice the logic has flipped but **technically you are not using linq**

Comment: It *could* be called the simplest, but it's a very wasteful solution.

Answer (score 1):

generally, you can not remove or add things to a collection in a foreach loop.  just set the where clause to return the results that you are looking for.

```
List<string> l = new List<string>();
l.Add("a");
l.Add("b");
l.Add("c");

// notice that the where clause is opposite of what you had before
l = list.Where( s=> s.CompareTo("a") <= 0 ).ToList();
```